# Dockerfile run executable

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile

I'm having a directory that contains a `Dockerfile` and a JAR file `foo.jar`.

In the `Dockerfile` I've written the following:

```
FROM java:8
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","foo.jar"]
```

I build the image with success by running

`docker build -t foo-example .`

Then I try to run it by running

`docker run -ti --rm -p 8080:8080 foo-example`

and I'm getting this error:

`Error: Unable to access jarfile foo.jar`

Any ideas?

Comment: just placing the jar file in the same directory as the dockerfile will NOT place the jar file into the docker image. You need to use the ADD command in your dockerfile.

Comment: indeed, I had not quite understood that, I added the jar file to the docker image and now it works fine, thanks!

Comment: @luthien it would be nice you accept the answer that helped you out.

Comment: @tvelykyy yes sure. All of the answers helped me, also the 1st comment, however I can accept only one and I guess the fairest is to accept the one that was posted earlier. Thanks a lot all of you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make `foo.jar` available inside the container, e.g. copy it inside and make sure to specify exact location while executing it. Read docker docs about [ADD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add) command.

Basically you need to add something along these lines:

```
ADD foo.jar foo.jar
```

Using [COPY](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) is another alternative:

```
COPY foo.jar ~/.
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use docker COPY or ADD command. COPY is more preferred as described here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#add-or-copy

```
FROM java:8
EXPOSE 8080
COPY foo.jar ~/.
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","foo.jar"]
```